# Запуск таймера без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, ajax

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при условии, когда выбрано в списке `<select name="closed"` значение Закрыто, начинался таймер в кнопке `<button id="countdown"`. Сейчас, если страницу перезагрузить, то все работает. Как запустить без перезагрузки?

Код: http://pastebin.com/3RRRFZth

Comment: Укажите кусок кода, который не работает в вопросе.

Answer (score 1):

Код у вас вставлен очень криво, пожалели бы людей)
Ответ на ваш вопрос прост

```
$('селект').on('change', function (e){
    if(e.currentTarget.value == 1) {
        $('#countdown').show();
    } else {
        $('#countdown').hide();
    }
});
```